# How to configure tomcat latest version on windows

Tags: tomcat

When entering local:8080 in chrome browser dialog box appears asking for username and password. where to get it. Tried with "tomcat" and "admin".

Comment: [Documentation is a wonderful thing](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) - Configuring Manager Application Access

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat, user name and password is to be set for different different roles as per your requirement. ex: for manager GUi and admin gui you can set the user name and password.
Make sure if there is any setting for Admin gui as well due to this it is asking the user name and password.

for accessing it check the tomcat-users.xml file, enter the following content if it is not available:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="12345" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

after this again restart the tomcat and launch the browser with url: localhost:8080
and for managing gui enter localhost:8080/manager/html